# R: By group, check if for each unique value of one var, there is at least one observation where the value of the var equals the value of another var

Tags: r, data.table

I think I am on the right direction with this code, but I am not quite there yet.

I tried finding something useful on Google and SE, but I did not seem to be able to formulate the question in a way that gets me the answer I am looking for.

I *could* write a *for-loop* for this, comparing for each *id* and for each unique value of *a* per row, but I strive to achieve a higher level of R-understanding and thus want to avoid loops.

```
id <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5)
a <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5,6)
b <- c(1,2,3,3,3,4,3,4,5,4,4,5,6,7,8)

require(data.table)
dt <- data.table(id, a, b)

dt
dt[,unique(a) %in% b, by=id]
tmp <- dt[,unique(a) %in% b, by=id]
tmp$id[tmp$V1 == FALSE]
```

In my example, *IDs* 2, 3 and 5 should be the result, the decision rule being: "By *id*, check if for each unique value of *a* if there is at least one observation where the value of *b* equals value of *a*."

However, my code only outputs *IDs* 2 and 5, but not 3. This is because for *ID* 3, the *4* is matched with the *4* of the previous observation.

The result should either output the IDs for which the condition is not met, or add a dummy variable to the original table that indicated whether the condition is met for the ID.

Comment: I think i have misunderstood but wth: `with(dat, unique(id[!ave(a==b, list(id, a), FUN=any)]))`

Comment: Try `dt[, !any(a==b), by=list(id,a)][, any(V1),by=id]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
dt[, all(sapply(unique(a), function(i) any(a == i & b == i))), by = id]

#   id    V1
#1:  1  TRUE
#2:  2 FALSE
#3:  3 FALSE
#4:  4  TRUE
#5:  5 FALSE
```

If you want to add a dummy variable to the original table, you can modify it like

```
dt[, check:=all(sapply(unique(a), function(i) any(a == i & b == i))), by = id]
```

Answer (score 1):

I wondered if I can find are more *data.table-esk* solution for this old question using the enhanced join capabilities which were introduced to `data.table` in version 1.9.6 (on CRAN 19 Sep 2015). With that version, `data.table` has gained the ability to join without having to set keys by using the `on` argument.

#### Variant 1

```
dt[a == b][dt[, unique(a), by = id], on = .(id, a == V1)][is.na(b), unique(id)]
```

> ```
> [1] 2 3 5
> ```

First, the rows of `dt` where `a` and `b` are equal are selected.  Only these rows are right joined with the unique values of `a` for each `id`. The result of the join is

```
dt[a == b][dt[, unique(a), by = id], on = .(id, a == V1)]
```

> ```
>    id a  b
> 1:  1 1  1
> 2:  2 2 NA
> 3:  3 3  3
> 4:  3 4 NA
> 5:  4 4  4
> 6:  4 4  4
> 7:  4 5  5
> 8:  5 5 NA
> 9:  5 6 NA
> ```

The `NA` values in column `b` indicate that no match is found. Any `id` which has an `NA` value indicates that OP's condition is not met.

#### Variant 2

```
dt[dt[, unique(a), by = id], on = .(id, a == V1, b == V1), unique(id[is.na(x.a)])]
```

> ```
> [1] 2 3 5
> ```

This variant right joins `dt` (unfiltered!) with the unique values of `a` for each `id` but the join conditions require matches in `id` as well as matches in `a` and `b`. (This resembles the `a == i & b == i` expression in [konvas' accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26466665/3817004). Finally, those `id`s are returned which have at least one NA value in the join result indicating a missing match.