# By group, check if for each unique value, there is at least one row where the value of the field equals another field's value

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am looking for a way to (analoguosly to [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26466117/r-by-group-check-if-for-each-unique-value-of-one-var-there-is-at-least-one-ob), which I posed in preparation for this question in order to formulate the problem in a programming language I am more familiar with) check if, for each group and for each value of one variable, there is an observation where the value of the first variable equals the value of the second variable.

I am very unfamiliar with SQL and only use MS Access via the GUI. I do not know how to formulate the question to get SQL-specific results.

I tried some aggregation queries, chaining multiple queries and a few combinations of if-statements, but neither worked out to produce this result.

An example table is:

```
id a b 
 1 1 1 
 1 1 2 
 1 1 3 
 2 2 3 
 2 2 3 
 2 2 4 
 3 3 3 
 3 3 4 
 3 4 5 
 4 4 4 
 4 4 4 
 4 5 5 
 5 5 6 
 5 5 7 
 5 6 8
```

The result should be **TRUE** for IDs 1 and 4, and **FALSE** for IDs 2,3 and 5. The decision rule being: "By *id*, check if for each unique value of *a* if there is at least one observation where the value of *b* equals the value of *a*."

As in the other question, the answer should either output only the IDs where the result is **FALSE**, or append a dummy variable to the dataset that indicates whether the condition is met or not.

Comment: Why doesn't the first row (1,1,1) satisfy your decision rule?

Comment: @HansUp Sorry, I messed up the wording, which was no problem in the referenced question, as I could provide sample code there. Corrected it to reflect what the output should be.

Comment: Still not sure I understand.  Seems to me (3,3,3) should make your decision criteria evaluate as True for ID 3, yet you say that one is False.

Comment: @HansUp No, for ID 3 the result is FALSE, because the "4" in variable a in row 3 of group 3 is not matched by the "5" in variable b. (3,3,3) by itself would return true, but with (3,4,5) in the group the whole thing must return false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to do two `group by`s.

Inner `group by`, for each `(id, a)` are there any `b` values that match the `a`

Outer `group by`, for each `id`, were there any `a` values that didnt have a matching `b`

```
select id, max(result) <> 0 as [result2]
from
(
  select id, sum(iif(a=b, 1,0)) > 0 as [result]
  from [table]
  group by id, a
)
group by id
```

Comment: For ID 3 the result is FALSE, because the "4" in variable a in row 3 of group 3 is not matched by the "5" in variable b. (3,3,3) by itself would return true, but with (3,4,5) in the group the whole thing must return false.

Comment: I think there will need to be a subquery.

Comment: @iraserd - Take a look at my update, `0` is `false`, `-1` is `true`

Comment: @Aducci I'm getting a Syntax Error in the FROM clause with that. Am I right doing this: I create a new query design, add the "table" to the query, change into SQL mode and paste your code, replacing the existing two lines.

Comment: @Aducci I managed to fix it, you have to put braces in "from [table]" and then you get a circular reference error. Then just rename the first [result] into [result2] and it works. If you update your post I can accept the answer.

Comment: @iraserd - I updated the answer based on your feedback, thank you for the fix